# Building a debian package that creates a shared object

Tags: debian, deb

I have a library which builds a shared object library. It is libnetfilter_cthelper library on git.netfilter.org. The library  on doing ./conifgure;make;make install, installs the shared object library. When I created a debian package, it does create a shared object but it does not have any symbols.

Is there any simple way to create a debian package that builds the shared object file? Any way to debug it? Or is there any good tutorial. I have been reading a lot of stuff that does not have clean steps into understanding or building a package.

Comment: What have you been using so far? `debhelper` and `dh-make` come to mind from your question, but I'm a bit surprised if you have not yet tried either.

Comment: @tripleee well, yes. I initially started with a template that we have, where I work, but finally realized that template is not good for shared objects. Finally, re-packaged everything with dh-make, seems to work fine now but I don't know what was broken there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best reference information for this is Dancer's, if you want to know all about what is expected to happen and all the ways it can break: http://www.netfort.gr.jp/~dancer/column/libpkg-guide/libpkg-guide.html . That's probably not what you're looking for, though; it's not a tutorial and could never be called "clean steps".

Without seeing your debian/rules file, it's hard to know what might have broken in your case. Do you mean that the .so file in your package didn't export any symbols, or that it didn't have any debug symbols? I would start debugging a problem like this by first checking whether the version of foo.so under `$builddir/debian/{$packagename,tmp}` has the right symbols exported. If not, the problem is in the upstream build system or in how you were using it.

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial, it has the things I didn't know and is a good reference. The problem got fixed when I re-packaged everything with dh_make on upstream source.